# Getting next element in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm looking for a generic way to get the next element within Selenium. Jquery has a .next() function and overloads to allow a given type so I imagine there may be a JS based solution available for Selenium.

Given it's such a useful feature I'd have imagined someone must have done it already by now.

Cheers,
Jamie

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to assume you mean when you select an element some selector (say `By.className("primary")`), and you want to get the next item that has that class name?

To do that, you need to call `driver.findElements(By.className("primary"))`.  This will give you a list of all of the elements that match that selector.  Then, you can pick whichever one suits your needs.

If however, next() actually returns the next sibling, then you can do it these ways:

- Javascript: element.nextSibling()
- CSS : element + *
- Xpath: element/following-sibling::*

(Replace element with your selector)

Comment: Ahh thanks. I think element.nextElementSibling is probably the way to go. 

I'm wanting something generic so, I can't take the current WebElement instance and return another one, effectively without any knowledge of the page.

Answer (score 4):

One of the possible ways to navigate to element under same hierarchy is to use `/../` in xpath as shown below:

```
current_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.widget.TextView[@text="Current element text"]/../android.widget.TextView[@text="Next element text"]')
```

Here it will:

1. Firstly navigate to `android.widget.TextView[@text = "Current element text"]`
2. Then it will go back to parent element i.e `android.widget.RelativeLayout` and select the next `android.widget.TextView[@text="Next element text"]` under the same hierarchy.